The sankey diagram made with d3 fails and has overlapping nodes
I have a problem making a sankey chart with d3. It has to be in an HTML file without using frameworks so that it can be sent without further ado.
The problem is that nodes 4 and 5 are overlapping and after node 7 there is a space that should be occupied by the nodes above.
I don't know if it is a problem of percentages in the values of the links, but they are fine because it is more or less the size I want them to be. If in addition to solve that can you help me to put the text at the top left inside the nodes, it would be appreciated.


const container = document.getElementById("container");
const width = container.offsetWidth;
const height = container.offsetHeight;

const svg = d3.select("svg")
  .attr("viewBox", `0 0 ${width} ${height}`)
  .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet");

const sankey = d3.sankey()
  .nodeWidth(130)
  .nodePadding(10)
  .size([width, height]);
const data = {
  "nodes": [{
      "node": 0,
      "name": "0",
      "level": 0
    },
    {
      "node": 1,
      "name": "1",
      "level": 1
    },
    {
      "node": 2,
      "name": "2",
      "level": 1
    },
    {
      "node": 3,
      "name": "3",
      "level": 1
    },
    {
      "node": 4,
      "name": "4",
      "level": 2
    },
    {
      "node": 5,
      "name": "5",
      "level": 2
    },
    {
      "node": 6,
      "name": "6",
      "level": 2
    },
    {
      "node": 7,
      "name": "7",
      "level": 2
    },
    {
      "node": 8,
      "name": "8",
      "level": 2
    },
    {
      "node": 9,
      "name": "9",
      "level": 2
    },
    {
      "node": 10,
      "name": "10",
      "level": 2
    },
    {
      "node": 11,
      "name": "11",
      "level": 3
    },
    {
      "node": 12,
      "name": "12",
      "level": 3
    },
    {
      "node": 13,
      "name": "13",
      "level": 3
    },
    {
      "node": 14,
      "name": "14",
      "level": 4
    }
  ],
  "links": [{
      "source": 0,
      "target": 1,
      "value": 0.57,
      "message": "hola"
    },
    {
      "source": 0,
      "target": 2,
      "value": 0.350,
      "message": "hola"
    },
    {
      "source": 0,
      "target": 3,
      "value": 0.14,
      "message": "hola"
    },
    {
      "source": 1,
      "target": 4,
      "value": 0.19195,
      "message": "hola"
    },
    {
      "source": 1,
      "target": 5,
      "value": 0.15735,
      "message": "hola"
    },
    {
      "source": 1,
      "target": 6,
      "value": 0.12365,
      "message": "hola"
    },
    {
      "source": 1,
      "target": 7,
      "value": 0.09705,
      "message": "hola"
    },
    {
      "source": 2,
      "target": 4,
      "value": 0.1527,
      "message": "hola"
    },
    {
      "source": 2,
      "target": 8,
      "value": 0.1164,
      "message": "hola"
    },
    {
      "source": 2,
      "target": 9,
      "value": 0.0809,
      "message": "hola"
    },
    {
      "source": 3,
      "target": 10,
      "value": 0.14,
      "message": "hola"
    },
    {
      "source": 5,
      "target": 11,
      "value": 0.1446,
      "message": "hola"
    },
    {
      "source": 6,
      "target": 12,
      "value": 0.133,
      "message": "hola"
    },
    {
      "source": 7,
      "target": 12,
      "value": 0.09705,
      "message": "hola"
    },
    {
      "source": 8,
      "target": 11,
      "value": 0.1164,
      "message": "hola"
    },
    {
      "source": 9,
      "target": 13,
      "value": 0.0809,
      "message": "hola"
    },
    {
      "source": 13,
      "target": 14,
      "value": 0.0809,
      "message": "hola"
    }
  ]
}


const graph = sankey(data);

graph.nodes.forEach(node => {
  node.x0 = node.level * (width / 5);
  node.x1 = node.x0 + sankey.nodeWidth();
});



const tooltip = d3.select(".tooltip");

svg.append("g")
  .selectAll(".link")
  .data(graph.links)
  .join("path")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .attr("d", d3.sankeyLinkHorizontal())
  .style("stroke-width", d => Math.max(1, d.width))
  .style("stroke", d => d.source.index === 0 ? "#9EC2E5" : "#FFCC80")
  .on("mouseover", (event, d) => {
    tooltip.style("display", "block")
      .html(d.message)
      .style("left", `${event.pageX + 5}px`)
      .style("top", `${event.pageY - 20}px`);
  })
  .on("mouseout", () => tooltip.style("display", "none"));

const node = svg.append("g")
  .selectAll(".node")
  .data(graph.nodes)
  .join("g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("transform", d => `translate(${d.x0},${d.y0})`)

node.append("rect")
  .attr("height", d => d.y1 - d.y0)
  .attr("width", sankey.nodeWidth())
  .style("fill", d => d.level === 0 ? "#4E79A6" : d.level === 1 ? "#9FCBE8" : "#F28E2C")
  .append("title")
  .text(d => d.name);

node.append("text")
  .attr("x", sankey.nodeWidth() / 2)
  .attr("y", d => (d.y1 - d.y0) / 2)
  .attr("dy", "0.35em")
  .text(d => d.name);
body,
html {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif, sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

h1 {
  color: #004B87;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

#container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 80vh;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke-opacity: 0.6;
}

.node text {
  fill: #000000;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-anchor: middle;
}

.node rect {
  cursor: default;
  fill-opacity: .9;
}

.tooltip {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #ccecf1;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  pointer-events: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: none;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 130px;
}

.link:hover {
  stroke-opacity: 1.5;
}
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-sankey/0.12.3/d3-sankey.min.js"></script>
<h1 style="color: #004B87;">Journey de Use Case Discovery</h1>
<div id="container">
  <svg></svg>
  <div class="tooltip"></div>
</div>




Why are you explicitly changing the calculated node.x0 and node.x1 positions?  This is causing your overlap and defeating the purpose of a sankey visualization by obscuring the connections between nodes.
